# On sequences of differentiable functions, prove that $\{f'_n\}$ converges uniformly to the derivative of the pointwise limit.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of functions that are differentiable on interval $[a,b]$ such that the sequence $\{f_n(x_0)\}$ converges at some point $x=x_0$ in $[a,b]$. If the sequence $\{f'_n\}$ converges uniformly to a function $g$ on $[a,b]$, then {$f_n$} must converge uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$ where $f'(x)\equiv g(x)$.

So I've tried writing out what this really means. I think it effectively comes down to proving that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left[\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f_n(x+h)-f_n(x)} h\right] = \lim_{h \to 0} \left[ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f_n(x+h)-f_n(x)} h \right]$$
$$g(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)} h$$
And for any given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta$ so that we have $$0<|h|<\delta \implies \left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)} h - g(x)\right|<\varepsilon$$

How do I continue from here, and if I shouldn't, which other path should I take?

Comment: Aren't they matching fine enough to attract interest? The limit equality does not fit in the title due to the limiting value of 150 characters. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like Fundamental Theorem of Calculus might do the trick.

Comment: That hasn't been covered yet. This is an introductory case on Analysis, this chapter particularly on functional Analysis. Only one theorem that may be involved here has been covered: continuous functions converging uniformly have a continuous limit function. And the definitions of pointwise and uniform convergence. Besides that not much..

Comment: Also, fundamental theorem of calculus requires that the functions in the sequence are $C^1$, which you do not necessarily know. It does, however, require mean value theorem, which hopefully you've seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $\epsilon > 0$, and choose $N$ sufficiently large that $|f_n(x_0)-f_m(x_0)| < \epsilon$ and $|f_n'(t)-f_m'(t)| < \frac{\epsilon}{(b-a)}$ for $n,m\ge N$. Now, use mean value theorem on the function $f_n-f_m$ for two arbitrary points $x_1,x_2\in [a,b]$ to get $|f_n(x_1) - f_m(x_1) + f_m(x_2) - f_n(x_2)| = (f_n-f_m)'(c)|x_1-x_2|$. By our choice of $N$ previously, this is bounded by $\epsilon$. Then $\|f_n-f_m\|_{\textrm{sup}} < 2\epsilon$, so the sequence converges uniformly.

Now, for some $x\in [a,b]$, let $g_n(t) = \frac{f_n(t)-f_n(x)}{t-x}$. Then $|g_n(t)-g_m(t)| = \frac{1}{|t-x|}|f_n(t)-f_m(t)+f_m(x)-f_n(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{b-a}$, so that the $g_n$ converge uniformly to $\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}$. The, by interchange of limits, $f'(x) = \lim_{t\to x} \lim_{n\to \infty} g_n(t) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \lim_{t\to x} g_n(t) = g(x)$

Comment: I don't get your final conclusion on the difference quotients.

Comment: Also, how is the {$x_0$} sequence relevant?

Comment: The $\{x_0\}$ is relevant to get, for arbitrary $x\in [a,b]$, the bound $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)| \le |f_n(x) - f_m(x) + f_m(x_0) - f_n(x_0)| + |f_n(x_0)-f_m(x_0)| < 2\epsilon$, hence the claim about $\|f_n-f_m\|$. I'll more explicitly deal with the difference quotient in an edit.

Comment: Oh all right and what about the final claim?

Comment: Updated response with details. Sorry about being a little terse at the beginning, but I hope this is clear.

Comment: @Daminark I am a little confused how $|f_n(x_1) - f_m(x_1) + f_m(x_2) - f_n(x_2)| < \epsilon$ $\implies $ $||f_n - f_m||_\infty < 2 \epsilon$? This may be obvious but can you please elaborate? This is the last line of paragraph 1.

Comment: @Black see my first reply to QuestionMaker